# jQuery Read More/Read Less appended after full text for Read Less state only

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I could use some guidance with this bit of jQuery. This seems to be a popular topic, and so far, I have the Read more/read less text changing on click, and the single instance working in isolation where there are multiple instances on the page.

What I need to do now is append the Read Less to the end of the full text. I have this working at the moment, but the toggleSlide (to slide Up) breaks as a result.

I'm learning jQuery at the moment (love it!) so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fulltext').hide();

    $('.blog-item .readmore').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().nextAll('.fulltext').first().slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read less...' ? 'Read more...' : 'Read less...');
        $(this).appendTo($('.fulltext'));
    });            
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Techbot/AuAKn/

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you're appending the .readmore anchor to the end after slide toggling, and that breaks the functionality of your dom traversing

```
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.fulltext').first().slideToggle('slow');
```

I have forked your fiddle and shown you a simpler way of doing it.  Now you just have to position the "read more" anchor with CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/AcQ6s/2/

Comment: I personally don't like using ".parent()" in this sort of context, if you need to add an extra wrapping div for any reason the javascript then stops working.

Comment: I wasn't using parent in this context.  I was quoting his code and saying it'll break.

I used parent in my fiddle because you need to be able to traverse up and back down to make sure you're only selecting the single instance of .fulltext and not all instances

Comment: @HighParkCoder I appreciate simplification whenever I can get it :) I can see what you've done and it definitely works nicely. I am integrating this into a CMS, so adding p class="fulltext" to each paragraph (there will be multiple paragraphs for full text), while perhaps an option using jquery, was why I'd wrapped it in a div. Any advice?

Comment: I think I can retain the fulltext wrapping div, as long as the read more anchor is outside of it. http://jsfiddle.net/Techbot/AuAKn/5/

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight tweak to HighParkCoder's answer, but it's more robust, and will stand up to making changes to the structure of each blog item. Instead, update the line too:

```
$(this).closest('.blog-item').find('.fulltext').slideToggle('slow');
```

It is also worth caching `$(this)` as you reference it several times in the code. It is always worth getting used to keeping your code more general so that if you decided to change the structure of your blog-item, the javascript with work. Using .parent() is tied far more closely to the current structure of your blog-item.

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/D7a6E/3/

Comment: We're splitting hairs here.  It's generally understood that if you make changes to the structure, you'll have to update the javascript.

In your case, what if he renames '.blog-item' to something else?  It will also break.  Either way, he'll need to recode his JS.

In my case, if he adds additional wrappers, it will break the JS, and in your case, if he renames the class name, it will also break.

Comment: I totally disagree with your logic. Changing class names is something that is unlikely to happen as that is changing existing structures. Whereas structural changes to support an image, or something similar is quite likely. It definitely is not generally accepted that a change to the HTML requires a change to JS. You should write your JS to be as independent of your HTML as possible to prevent this sort of issue.

Answer (score -1):

You almost have it; just a few adjustments.  First, reorder your HTML:

```
<div class="blog-item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at urna ac
        leo vulputate egestas a ut odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec
        in erat velit, eu ultricies diam.

    <div class="fulltext">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at urna ac
            leo vulputate egestas a ut odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
    </div>
    <a class="readmore" href="#">Read more...</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Then, just toggle the text on click:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fulltext').hide();

    $('.blog-item .readmore').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.fulltext').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read less...' ? 'Read more...' : 'Read less...');
    });
});
```

That should do the trick!  Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/AuAKn/1/

Comment: Almost.. If he uses $('.fulltext').slideToggle('slow'), it will toggle EVERY instance of .fulltext, not just the one the user is currently on.  Since there will be multiple items with "read more", you need to traverse up to the parent and select only its child ".fulltext" to slide toggle.

Comment: Agreed HighParkCoder. Apologies for not making this more clear in JSfiddle Sable Foste. I've added a second instance now, and the append has even worse repercussions then I noticed initially :|
http://jsfiddle.net/Techbot/AuAKn/3/